# VBA: Double for loop through very large amounts of data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large amount of data stored in a csv file (around 60mb) which has a list of names and two dates adjacent to the name i.e.

```
A1name1   B1date1   C1date2
A2name2   B2date1   C2date2
```

I have another file which has a list of names:

```
names1
names2
names3
names4
```

I want to take names1 for example, search through the big database of names and return date1 and date 2 if names1 is found. I have done this using a double for loop. Pseudocode for it is as follows:

```
For i = 1 to SMLendofrow
    for j = 1 to LRGendofrow
       if cells(i,"A").value = lrgwkbook.wrksheet.cells(j,"A").value then
               cells(i,"B").value =lrgwkbook.wrksheet.cells(j,"B").Value
               cells(i,"C").value =lrgwkbook.wrksheet.cells(j,"C").Value
           end if
        next j
next i
```

Now this code works perfectly however it is simply just too long. As the large workbook which has all the names is very large it takes around 10 minutes to search through all of it. Is tehre a more efficient method? I have used python as an alternative and that gets it done in 2 minutes but I want something specifically with VBA.

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered pushing the ranges into arrays then comparing the arrays directly rather than iterating across the cells?  Should be faster.  Also, consider trying [codereview.se] for this question as that's the correct place for optimisation of code that already works...

Comment: Apologies didn't know. I'll give the array method a shot.

Comment: @james1395 try my code in my answer below, you can use the `Match` function and save the inner loop. Let me know if this helped you

Comment: in a comment of yours you said _"it's over a million names"_: how have you succeeded in opening such a file in excel given its 1048576 maximum row number?

Answer (score 2):

Depends. If your RAM size and number of names in the second file allow it, 'Id recommend to have a single loop for the larger file, push name - date1 and name - date2 key-value pairs into two dictionaries (or in other languages, hash tables) and when it's done, a separate loop (not embedded into the other) process the other file and get the names from the two hashes.

You'll have to have microsoft.scripting.runtime referenced in the project.

Comment: Unforuntately it's over a million names, so it won't even open in excel fully (csv file). I'm going to need a work around

Comment: Oh, that's not cool. Can you explain why you need VBA? I'd recommend to load them into a database with Talend, Pentaho or just pure SQL and then do the aggregation there. Much easier, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the CSV file to MDB (Access database) and then connect this database and do the necessary things. It works faster than above method.
Note: Everytime need to recreate the MDB from CSV if changes made to CSV file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Match` function, it will save you the inner loop (and a lot of precious run-time), see code below (just the section you need to modify)

```
Dim MatchRow As Long
Dim SearchedRng As Range

' set the range for "Match" all active rows and columns >> modify as needed
' I assumed "LRGendofrow" is the last row
Set SearchedRng = lrgwkbook.wrksheet.Range("A1:C" & LRGendofrow)

For i = 1 To SMLendofrow
   ' For j = 1 To LRGendofrow
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Cells(i, "A").Value, SearchedRng, 0)) Then
        MatchRow = Application.Match(Cells(i, "A").Value, SearchedRng, 0)
        Cells(i, "B").Value = lrgwkbook.wrksheet.Cells(MatchRow, "B").Value
        Cells(i, "C").Value = lrgwkbook.wrksheet.Cells(MatchRow, "C").Value
    Else ' "names" record not found >> do something

        ' in my example I put #NA in cells, to know it's not found
        Cells(i, "B") = CVErr(xlErrNA)
        Cells(i, "C") = CVErr(xlErrNA)
    End If

Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

to avoid the inner (and bigger) loop, you could use this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim namesRng As Range
    Dim f As Range, cell As Range

    With Worksheets("Names") '<-- change "Names" with actual name of your sheet with the list of names
        Set namesRng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| get the list of names form cell A1 down to last non empty row
    End With

    With Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\...\data.csv").Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns(1) '<-- open your CSV file and refer to "used" cells in its column "A"
        For Each cell In namesRng '<-- loop through names list
            Set f = .Find(what:=cell.value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<-- try finding current name in referenced range of csv file
            If Not f Is Nothing Then cell.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2).value = f.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2).value '<--| if found, then write its two adjacent cells values next to current name ones
        Next cell
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```